# Why Windows is not booting from the disk

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8, boot, multi-boot

After Ubuntu 13.10, my Windows 8 was not loading properly. So I decided to repair Windows by booting from the disk. When I starts my system it ask to press any key to boot from CD or DVD. When I press any button it goes to the grub menu, instead of booting the disk. Why is it so ? How can I boot from the disk ?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry.. That was a mistake. Now I edited it.

Comment: Did you change the boot order of your devices so the optical drive is used before your HDD?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you boot up your PC, hit the Alt and F8 button repeatedly and choose your Boot Option.

---

Use your arrow's on your keyboard to choose the option.

Also take a look at this : http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/open-advanced-startup-options-windows-8.htm